# Are there any security issues with getting the IP address of a user?

Tags: ip

So I've found a way to get the IP address of a user on a popular website without taking them out of said website (i.e. without making them click any links) by making them (the user) send a request to an arbitrary url, and by doing this you are able to get their:

- IP address
- User agent (on mobile it will show their operative system and the version of the app they are using)

And I'm wondering if there are any security issues for this... It is also possible to target a specific user or many users at once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can a hacker do with an IP address?](/questions/19018/), [An attacker has my IP address;So what?](/questions/79583/), [Is publishing your public IP address a security threat?](/questions/35160/).

Comment: @Buzzyy What is the issue with it?

Comment: @Buzzyy If by "location" you mean "country", then yes. But again, what use is it to an attacker that I live in Austria?

Comment: @MechMK1 Oh, I heard that they could find a more exact location, but I guess not. I’ll delete my comment.